# Functions - Odd numbers and surjectivity

Tags: functions, relations

I'm going through my textbook here and a lot of the examples show surjective functions that only map, say $$ \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$

But it just occurred to me what if I wanted to come up with a function that is surjective but more restrictive? Like Odd -> Odd? I'm not sure why but I'm having some real trouble coming up with one and it's bugging me. Where would I even start?

Comment: Do you mean function maps odd numbers to odd numbers?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: What about this?  $$f:\Bbb{R} \ni x \mapsto x^3 \in \Bbb{R}$$

Comment: Yeah, I can see why that is indeed surjective, but if I were to restrict the domain and codomain to only odd numbers, would it also be surjective? I'm so sorry for the dumb question, I am just finding this so hard to get my head round :[

Comment: Odd is usually defined for integers.  How do you define it for reals?

Comment: Why not just the identity function on the domain odd numbers?  Can't get simpler than that.

Comment: A less simple one could be $f (n)=2\lfloor \frac n4 \rfloor +1$

Answer (score 1):

On any set $S$, the function from $S$ to $S$ defined by

$$f(x)=x$$

is a surjection (in fact, it is also a bijection) from $S$ to $S$.

Comment: Would it be possible to restrict the domain and codomain of that function to strictly odd numbers, though? Seems like $$ x $$ can be of any value in that example :[

Comment: @potatonotjacket Yes -- simply make your set $S$ the set of odd numbers.

Comment: Part of a definition of a function is defining itdomain.  So $f:S \to S $ can take in any value of $S $ and indeed *must* take in *every* value of $S $.  So if you want a function that can only half odd integers as input you *must* restrict its domain to the odd integers.  So if $S $={odd integers} then $f:S\to S; f (x)=x $ is a function just on the odd integers.